# iterate over dynamic json C# (console application)

Tags: c#, json, console-application

I have a json string that contains the data below:

```
[
  {
    "RecordId": "1800",
    "CrewId": "M9703",
    "Rank": "3RD OFFICER",
    "VesselCode": "Honourable Henry Jackman",
    "MovementType": "ON LEAVE",
    "StartDate": "2009-01-13",
    "EndDate": "2012-06-30",
    "DueDate": "2009-01-02",
    "StartLoc": "",
    "EndLoc": "",
    "CompletionReason": "",
    "Remarks": "",
    "Last_Edited_Date": "2013-10-18"
  },
  {
    "RecordId": "4880",
    "CrewId": "M9703",
    "Rank": "2ND OFFICER",
    "VesselCode": "Ore Salobo",
    "MovementType": "ON LEAVE",
    "StartDate": "2013-02-10",
    "EndDate": "2013-08-26",
    "DueDate": "2012-12-28",
    "StartLoc": "",
    "EndLoc": "",
    "CompletionReason": "NORMAL DUTIES",
    "Remarks": "",
    "Last_Edited_Date": "2013-10-18"
  }
]
```

I want to display it as key value pair in the console..

I have tried this for displaying it as key and value pair:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
var Dejson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
foreach (var pair in Dejson)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

But it only shows `:` in the console.

Comment: What is the `res` argument in `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);`?

Comment: res is a "list" coming from webservice.

Comment: the value of json is showned above.

Comment: ...what is the data type of the List? Is it a `List<string>`? Please show the declaration of `res`. This is likely where your problem resides.

Comment: Why you need to SerializeObject res if already has list of "object" can you not do a ToDictionary on res itself to get keyvaluepair you want ?

Answer (score 1):

```
       // assuming res is list of objects and RecordId is string not integer/long
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);

        Dictionary<string, res> Dejson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json).ToDictionary(k => k.RecordId, v => v); 

        foreach ((KeyValuePair<string, res> pair in Dejson)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JArray obj = JArray.Parse(json);    
Response.Write(obj[0]["RecordId"]);
```

Using above code you can get desired values from JSon object.